# Access Dask scheduler from an external docker container

Tags: docker, dask

I have started a dask-scheduler at host A. Host A has docker engine installed. So, host A has multiple network interfaces:

- 192.168.10.250 (default IP for host A)
- 172.17.0.1 (host A IP address in bridge network (i.e., docker0))

I tested a simple client, from within host A, to both IP addresses and works well

Now, I started a Docker container on the same host A without specifying any networks, so the docker container connects to the default bridge network and receives IP address 172.17.0.2. Within the docker container, I try to start a client that connects to the dask scheduler on the host A as follows:

client=Client('172.17.0.1:8786')

but each time I receive the following error:

IOError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://172.17.0.1:8786' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time

I tried to change the network drive for the container to "host" instead of "bridge" but then I receive the following error:

distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in : Stream is closed

please help

Regards

Comment: Can you share the actual `docker run` command you used?

Comment: docker run -it --rm --name test [--net host] <my docker image>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Problem solved.

I realized the problem was that python 2.7 was used inside docker image. When I used python 3.6, it worked (even without the --net host)

Regards